# Можно ли использовать тригер который валидирует информацию

Tags: sql

Ребят, у меня вопрос у меня есть 3 таблицы: 
1.Материалы заявки( в которой есть информация о заявке) она содержит 2 foreign key (firm_exp_id) и (firm_imp_id).

Эти ключи связывают таблицу app_mats  с таблицей firm в которой содержаться информация о фирмах. Они указывают на фирму которая експортирует и фирма которая импортирует   [Вот как выглядят таблицы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbona.jpg)

Таблица firms связана с таблицей country.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при заполнении делалась проверка:
или фирма-отправитель должна быть с Украины или фирма-получатель была должна быть с Украины.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором - лучше отдать контроль подсистеме поддержания целостности данных, чем пытаться строить свои костыли.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!